# Some images among thousands return 403 Forbidden

Tags: php, html, image, http-status-code-403

When downloading a large amount of pictures (via `cURL` / `file_get_contents`) from a server, about 99% of them display smoothly on a website, but a few of them (around 15-20 out of over 15k) do not show up. Instead, they return a `403 Forbidden` error.

Permissions have been set to `777` for all files and folders but nothing changes.

Has anyone else had the same problem and was able to solve it?

Comment: Anything strange about the filenames - e.g., / or \ or ? or something else that might get caught up in the filename->URL->filename translation?

Comment: Do the same images always return with 403 or is it random?

Comment: @ManuelOtto always the same images. But it's strange since I've tried to remove the image and reload it manually, rename it but it's always the same 403.

Comment: @manassehkatz I've just double checked the filenames and they seem to be identical to every other picture which works perfectly.

Comment: This question doesn't seem to be about programming. It might be better suited for [webmasters.SE] Stack Exchange, although without more information, they probably won't be able to answer it, either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filenames of the 403 images all contained inside the word "chat". That's the reason why the server returned 403 Forbidden.
Hope someone find it helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create a php script that returns content of files

```
<?php
$file = file_get_contents("path/to/file");
//You can add headers using header("..."); for make sure that images will works. 
//var_dump($file);exit; // uncomment to check is it even loading #debug
die($file);
```

Comment: var_dump($file) prints bool(false)

Comment: The function returns the read data or FALSE on failure. So you've got wrong path to file or have no permission to read data. You should check the source of path (if you are using database then maybe some rows have wrong data) (or content of file is "false" => then you will get a string "false" as result)